# The seemingly unnecessary “out” in phrasal verbs

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

The preposition part of some phrasal verbs seem to add no additional meaning to the verb. Take as an example “out” in the following phrasal verbs;

Write out, Miss out, Test out, List out, Type out, Try out, Skip out (on sth), Write out, Rent out, Separate (them) out, Clean out, Help out, Print out.

how does the preposition “out” change the meaning or emotion of these verbs? E.g, what is the difference between the sentences in the following pairs?

a) He really helped me.
b) He really helped me out.

a) Write it!
b) Write it out!

a) I tested that idea.
b) I tested out that idea.

Comment: Closely related: [any difference between 'testing out' and 'testing'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/579126/any-difference-between-testing-out-and-testing)

Comment: Most of these are essentially resultative, stressing a laying or spreading or throwing or giving _out_ (from the original position). 'Miss / skip out' (as with 'leave out') stress separation, as probably does 'help out [of a hole]'. 'Test out' is giving me cause to wonder.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: for me, "test it out" is a synonym for "try it out".

Comment: The doctor told me to cut out smoking = eliminate cigarettes // The doctor told me to cut down on smoking  = reduce the number of cigarettes // The doctor told me to cut smoking = ambiguous, eliminate or reduce?

Comment: See also [What's the difference between "write" and "write out"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/346321/191178)

Comment: We helped him out of a tricky situation = He managed to avoid trouble OR he escaped unharmed // We helped him in a tricky situation = He had assistance, but we don't know how successful that was.

Comment: Out suggests **completeness**. Like I told him vs. I told him off. Especially with Write it out (fully) and Tested out that idea (to an end).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth can we say “out” add a layer of meaning referring to “towards external world” or “implementing” or “physicalization” ?

Comment: Mods: With respect, how is this not fully worthy of a place on ELU? // raz,, The Collins Cobuild Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs, with its Particles Index, may well have the judgements scholars have come to on the specific semantic thrusts of the actual examples of 'V + out' you ask about. With 14 different sub-usages, a one-size-fits-all explanation is not realistic.

Answer (score 6):

The *Collins Cobuild Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs* has a *Particles Index*. The introduction to the index makes it clear that in many cases the particle emphasises, modifies or extends the meaning of the same verb without the particle.

The index then lists the common meanings of each phrasal verb particle. It has 14 different meanings of the particle **out**.

For example, the main dictionary entry on *help out* states:

> If you *help out* or *help someone out*, you do them a favour, such as
> lending them money or doing some of their work.

The particles index lists *help out* under *Section 13: Supporting and helping*, along with *bail out* and several others.

*Write out*, *print out*, *type out* and *clean out* are in *Section 8: Thoroughness and completeness*, with many others such as *carry out* and *hear out*. The entry to this section states:

> You use *out* in combination with verbs which describe activities in
> order to indicate that the activity is done thoroughly or completely.

*Test out* and *list out* do not appear in the dictionary but could be included alongside the others in Section 8.

*Skip out* is in *Section 1: Leaving*, which includes the introductory text "*leaving a work activity*".

*Separate out* is in *Section 11 Arranging, dividing, selecting, and distributing*. Also in this section is *rent out*. But *rent* and *rent out* have opposite meanings, at least in my variant of British English.

So, in summary, it is not always true that particles "*add no additional meaning*".

Comment: Marvellous. And apparently you can get a copy for less than 2% of the cost of a new CGEL.

Comment: That's quite a resource. Probly oughta add it to the lists on Meta.